# Cadence cron workflow disappearing from workflow list after 24 hours, but still running

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I've setup a Cadence cron workflow to execute on a specific day of each month. After registering the workflow with:

```
cadence --address localhost:7933 \
  --domain domain-name workflow start --tl TaskListName \
  --wt WorkflowTypeName --dt 60 --et 60 \
  --wid Workflow.Cron --cron '0 23 23 * *'
```

I can see it appearing in the Cadence web UI with the `Open` status.

I also see the workflow info when I use the Cadence CLI with:

```
cadence --address localhost:8933 --domain domain-name list --workflow_id Workflow.Cron --open
```

However, after about 24 hours, it disappears from the Workflow list view of Cadence UI. I can still access the workflow's execution details page by using its `run_id`. On that page, I can see the workflow is still active and waiting for the moment defined by the cron expression to be reached.

Also, at this point, if I use the Cadence CLI with the command I mentioned earlier, it doesn't list the workflow anymore.

If I use the `show` command instead:

```
cadence --address localhost:8933 --domain domain-name show --workflow_id Workflow.Cron
```

I get the following:

```
  1  WorkflowExecutionStarted  {WorkflowType:{Name:WorkflowTypeName},  
                                TaskList:{Name:TaskListName},                   
                                Input:[], ExecutionStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds:60,              
                                TaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds:60,                             
                                ContinuedFailureDetails:[], LastCompletionResult:[],           
                                OriginalExecutionRunID:9bdc7e76-1b93-47eb-b566-81d4f115a950,   
                                Identity:cadence-cli@stenix,                                   
                                FirstExecutionRunID:9bdc7e76-1b93-47eb-b566-81d4f115a950,      
                                Attempt:0, CronSchedule:0 23 23 * *,                           
                                FirstDecisionTaskBackoffSeconds:95387}                         
History Source: Default Storage
```

The cron is set to execute a few hours later today, so I've yet to know whether the workflow will continue with its activities as expected or not. But I am wondering why the workflow is disappearing from the Cadence UI and from the CLI list command after ~24 hours?

I've also tried providing an `--earliest_time` to the CLI `list` command.

**EDIT**: The workflow carried on with its activities at the scheduled time. Also, it reappeared in the workflow list after/during execution. However, new cron workflows are still disappearing from the list ~24h after their creation.

Comment: I'm suspecting you might be using last 24 hours filter on the UI. Could you check the time filters on the top right? I'm surprised the CLI list command didn't show your workflow. By default earliest time is 0 and latest time is now.

Comment: The filter that is set in the UI is the default one (StartTime within the last 30 days), [screenshot here](https://imgur.com/a/FY9iypL)